# Appending characters before the filename of all layers in a GeoPackage in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql, spatial-database, geopackage, rename

I have a geopackage which contains around 30 files. I want to put a "mmbl_" before the actual file name for all the layers in the said geopackage. Is there a an SQL expression to automate this renaming process in QGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must rename layers one by with SQL `ALTER TABLE...` See https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html. For renaming many layers automatically you should make a script that first gets the list of the tables to rename. I suppose that you interested in just the spatial tables so you can get the list with

`SELECT table_name from gpkg_contents`

For renaming you can use ogrinfo. The command would look like

`ogrinfo -sql "ALTER TABLE first_table RENAME TO mmbl_first_table" my_geopackage.gpkg`

You must not try to rename the table with generic SQLite tools and native `RENAME TO` https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html or otherwise you will break the geopackage. The native `alter table` can rename the table and update the triggers, but it does not update the references in the metadata tables `gpkg_contents`, `gpkg_geometry_columns`, `gpkg_extensions`, and others.